# VS code icons meanings?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[image: icons]

How can i find these icons meanings? And also there are same codes but different icons there     (2x LN10) why?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions Does the table answer your question?

Comment: Yes i found it now . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them on the IntelliSense section of the VSCode docs. They typically refer to the types of the variable or value that they are referencing and can be modified by extensions as well. You can read more about them here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions